# Shouldn't it be necessary to put "~/" at the beginning of script files that are not in the same directory?

Tags: javascript, .net-core

How can scripts run without adding "~/" at the beginning of the script address path, even though "AdminLayout" is not in the same folder as "inspinia-gh-pages"?
Since "AdminLayout" and "inspinia-gh-pages" are not in the same directory, shouldn't we put "~/" at the beginning of the script address path?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVjMu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSJIx.png)

Thanks

Comment: I think it depends on your OS.

Comment: In another example; What makes me think more is that if I add "~/" to the beginning of the "src" extension of the <img>, the browser does not see the image file. If I do not add "~/" to the beginning of the "src" extension of the <img>, the browser sees the image file.

Comment: I believe one would be starting from the webroot (in Linux?) and the other is relative. Where is your JS file in relation to your cshtml file? You don't show the contents of `inspinia-gh-pages` folder, but there is a `js` folder that appears to be its sibling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML starting a path with `/` signifies that URL that ends up being generated should be based off of the root of the website, instead of being relative to the page that you're currently on.

For example, if this script is on https://example.com/some/subpage:

```html
<script src="/scripts/something.js"></script>
```

...The browser will find it by making a request to `https://example.com/scripts/something.js`.

The usage of `~` is a pattern that is popular in ASP.NET where [the framework generates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178116(v=vs.100)) the correct URL when rendering the page to the browser, replacing `~` with an appropriate path that is accessible by the browser. This is a called a virtual path in .NET context.

The reason why your code works without it is because the root of your website – for the browser and the end user – is `wwwroot`, where the `inspinia-gh-pages` directory is located as well. So if you imagine `/` == `wwwroot`, it makes sense that `wwwroot` + `inspinia-gh-pages/3s/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"` ends up delivering jQuery.

Comment: I'm starting to understand, thank you very much @Lasse
The ~/ operator is an auxiliary operator for ASP.NET to fetch the running root directory.
In addition, ASP.NET determines the root directory of all the files I used for the example I used in my question as wwroot. (If we open the folders in the file explorer, we can see that they are not under the same folder :) )

Comment: Happy to hear it, @Karayeniceri :) Feel free to accept my answer if you feel like it answered your question